# Need to reinstall printer (HP Lasejet 1018) plugin everytime

Tags: hp, plugins, hplip, laserjet

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit and HPLIP 3.13.6. Anytime I want to print something my printer doesn't work. There are no error codes shown. When I reinstall the plugin problem is solved. Must I do this always ? (Note : I didn't have the problem with Ubuntu 12.xx)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your username to the lp group on Ubuntu after installation?

```
sudo usermod -a -G lp $USER
```

This will add your username to the lp group.

As a reference: [compiling and installing hplip with a classical way](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/distros/ubuntu.html)